Why is the bevel/subdivision modifier messing up the mesh of my column?
I want to add a bevel and subdivision modifier to the column I made.
However, when I do this, I get the following result:
Why is this happening?
Here is the file:


EDIT: Okay, I changed the typology and recalculated the normals. So, the bevel works mostly. When I add Subdivision, something is still going wrong. So, where the mesh is getting messy that's also the part where the Bevel stops working. I feel like the typology is sort of divided into two. I added the new file.


You have flipped normals and overlapping faces:

You need to rework your topology, for example you could only keep the corner edges and fill with CtrlE > Bridge Edge Loops:

Second file: The problem is that for the moment your Bevel modifier is set to Limit Method > Angle, it creates bevel between the faces, even with a low angle, which prevents the smoothness between the faces. You'd better right click > Shade Smooth, select these edges, assign them Bevel Weight:

Then choose Limit Method > Weight:


Any ideas about the other issue that came up?

Please share your file again

I put the new file in there

I've edited my answer
